# Excel keeps crashing after saving VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that is managing staff caseloads and managed to find some VBA on here that helped to sort that data effectively, but now it keeps crashing whenever I save. I'm a bit of a beginner so the code is hashed together from various question I have found on this site (thanks by the way! amazing resource!)

Is anyone able to look at my code and see anything glaringly obvious please? My worksheet only crashes after I click the button I have attached this to and then try to save immediately after

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
 Dim LRow As Long
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim v As Integer
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Array("TBC", "Waiting", "Active", "Closed")
    v = Application.CustomListCount

    Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Cases")

    With Ws
        LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngDB = .Range("A5", .Range("T" & LRow))
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("J3"), Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:=v
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("G1"), Order:=xlDescending
          With .Sort
            .SetRange rngDB
            .Header = xlNo
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
    Application.DeleteCustomList v
End Sub
```

Comment: So, to be clear, does crash occur during the code running? Or the code runs correctly and the crash happens with a subsequent save?

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but don't delete the list at the end.

Comment: @SolarMike the crash only occurs after running the code. The code works as I think it should visually on my table. I have even isolated that one code and the table in case it's running too many things at once but still an issue. If i save the document without clicking the button it saves as it should

Comment: @PauloACoelho this actually appears to help - I will keep trying it to see if it does it again but it was crashing immediately every time before. thank you!